# Changing background color of body using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

New to JS. I'm trying to change the background color of the body randomly using Javascript, and can't figure out why the code I have doesn't work:

```
var colors = ["#e88f84", "#e8bb84", "#d2e884"];

function randomize() {
    var randomHex = colors[Math.floor(Math.random * colors.length)];
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = randomHex;
}

<body>
    <div id="text">
        <script>randomize()</script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Math.random` is a method, you need to call it to get a random number. As `Math.random` returns function reference, the expression `Math.random * colors.length` returns `NaN`. And `Math.floor(NaN)` also return `NaN`.

```
var randomHex = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
                                             ^^
```

```js
var colors = ["#e88f84", "#e8bb84", "#d2e884"];

function randomize() {
  var randomHex = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = randomHex;
}

randomize();
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="text">
    Some text
  </div>
</body>
```

To improve the code, you can use IIFE which will get called automatically and will keep the variables local.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var colors = ["#e88f84", "#e8bb84", "#d2e884"];

    var randomHex = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = randomHex;
}());
```

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var colors = ["#e88f84", "#e8bb84", "#d2e884"]
  var randomHex = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = randomHex;
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Practically your code will never work. First of all, your "colors" array is missing a semicolon at the end. Second, Math.random is a function, not a variable. It must have parantheses (). Your codes misses them. Everything else is fine, I have tested it on my own laptop

Comment: Whoops, forgot that semicolon when I retyped the variable definition in StackOverflow. Thanks for pointing out the missing parentheses.